# Xcode CoreData CreateNSManagedObject Subclass creating an extra import statement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, xcode8

I have an Xcode 8 project using Swift 3 using CoreData. When I use the Create NSManagedObject feature, it seems to create an extra import statement at the top, which in turn causes an error in my project. I just wanted to let everyone know that if you delete the import statement that seems to solve the issue. Not sure if this is a bug in Xcode 8?

Here is an screen grab of that extra import: (see line 11)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

no need to generate it yourself. Xcode take care of it for you. Just use the entity name as class name in your code.

```
let anHistory = History(entity: yourEntity, insertInto: yourContext)
```

Comment: There could be several reasons why you want to generate the code manually so your answer doesn't make any sense in this context.